# Permutations of subsets and subsequent run-time analysis

Tags: java, algorithm, permutation, combinations

I have 2 questions:

1. I would like to generate the permutations of subsets e.g. There are 20 possible amino acids and 5 positions where they can occur. What are the total permutations that can occur (in text)
2. Once I have this list of permutations certain values will be assinged to each one and I would like to look up any given permutation at run time. The first idea that comes to mind is a look-up table, but I was wondering if there might be a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 5):

1. You want combinations of length 5, not permutations. This is a standard problem, which can be solved with recursion. Use [`CombinationGenerator`](http://www.merriampark.com/comb.htm) if you don't want to write it yourself.
2. Number the combinations using base 20 (not to be confused with the chemical definition of base). Use a hashtable if you'll be storing data for a limited subset of combinations, or a look-up array if you'll be most of them.

Comment: You can even use the array when you only use *almost all* permutations, it might still be more efficient (you will have to run performance tests to find the threshold).

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants. It sounds like he's actually interested in combinations or arrangements ("There are 20 possible amino acids **and 5 positions where they can occur** "), but definitely not permutations.

Comment: @Space That's what I meant to mean, I'll clarify. @IVlad You're right, I'll change.